# Clicking on a link clicks the image behind it

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click one link in a drop-down list, and the link is over an image which is also clickable. When I click the link, the image behind get clicked by selenium

The web page is:
https://www.youdao.com/w/eng/hello/#keyfrom=dict2.index

If you click the arrow beside the search input, one language list will show. The second and third language overlaps the ad image. If I click them manually, the language will be selected correctly. But selenium will always click the image behind.

The whole test script is as below

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('')
driver.get('https://www.youdao.com/w/eng/hello/#keyfrom=dict2.index')
driver.maximize_window()

#another language select arrow on a different page
another_arrow = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.arrow')
another_arrow.click()

time.sleep(0.5)

korean_lang = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[rel='ko']"))).click()
#driver.quit()
```

I expect the clicked language is selected, but selenium will click the image below and open a different page.

If clicking the first and last language which are not over the image, it works as expected.

Comment: try this `By.CSS_SELECTOR("[rel='ko']")` instead of `By.LINK_TEXT, u'中韩'.encode('utf8')`

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried( By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[rel='ko']"). But it still doesn't work:(

Comment: Can anyone help? Is this a chromedriver bug?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is
1. Get dropdown webelement
2. Get all values in the dropdown element by using find_elements_by_tag_name
3. Click on desired element using index

```
dropdownWebelement = driver.find_element_by_id("langSelection")
allValuesInDrowdown = dropdownWebelement.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

allValuesInDrowdown[1].click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work neither. It still clicks the image behind instead of the language selected. My problem is not element not being found. It is even if I have found the element, clicking it will click the image behind it:(.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking it directly with the javascript from the executeScript method:

```
#remove the click after the webdriverwait
korean_lang = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[rel='ko']")))
#click the element directly with executeScript(javascript)
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", korean_lang)
```

Hope this works

Comment: Yes, this works. But I really want to simulate user operation instead of bypassing the GUI.  Thanks any way.